# A particle is constrained to move around the unit circle in the xy plane according to (x,y,z) = (cos(t^2),sin(t^2),0) t >= 0

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, vectors

A particle is constrained to move around the unit circle in the xy plane according to (x,y,z) = (cos(t^2),sin(t^2),0) t >= 0
At what point should the particle be released to hit a target of (2,0,0)?

I found the velocity vector and speed, but now I am stuck.

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: At the point the particle should be released to hit the target of (2,0,0)

Comment: Note that when the object is released from the circle it will travel in a straight line tangent to the point on the circle from where it was released. So what line is tangent to the circle that goes through the point (2,0,0)?

Comment: Would i have to find the unit tangent vector?

Comment: You've already found the velocity vector. So for what $\theta$ do you have $\vec{v}(\theta)t+\vec{x}(\theta) = 2 \hat{i}$?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not entirely sure. Should I be thinking about the tangent line equation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, find the point on the circle where the tangent pass trough (2,0,0), but be careful with the sign, because you will get two solutions that correspond to the two different directions of rotation (clockwise and counterclockwise). You must use the solution in the 4th quadrant that corresponds to the counterclockwise solution.
the lower part of the circumference is: $y=-\sqrt(1-x^2)$ and the derivative is $y'=\frac{x}{\sqrt(1-x^2)}$
so you need top find $x$ such that: $y-0=y'(x-2)$ which is:
$-\sqrt(1-x^2)=\frac{x}{\sqrt(1-x^2)}(x-2)$
then find x=1/2 and from x find $t=\sqrt{\arccos(.5)}$.

Parametrizing:
the derivative is $(-2t\sin(t^2), 2t\cos(t^2), 0)$, so the tangent is $m=-1/\tan(t^2)$
So we need to find t such that:

$\sin(t^2)-0=-[1/\tan(t^2)][\cos(t^2)-2]$ after minor work you get $t=\sqrt{\arccos(.5)}$

Comment: What would I plug in for t(0)?

Comment: do you mean t=0?

Comment: do you need help finding x?

Comment: Yes, although I think I'm supposed to solve this in a different way, perhaps by parametrizing.

Comment: perhaps is easier parametrizing, but I just could came up with that

Comment: how would you do this by parametrizing?

Comment: not sure, I am sorry

Comment: ok, is still easier, I'll update

Comment: Would that be the quickest way to do it?

Comment: I think so, though nothing is completely sure